# COM порт вместо кириллицы принимает байты, соответствующие "***", хотя в других случая использования этой ошибки нет, в чем может быть проблема?

Tags: python, кодировка, com-порт, pyserial

Значит, есть ком порт. С ним работаю через pyserial. COM порт соединяет Raspberry PI с платформой, и по нему передается текст, который есть на видеовыходе с платформы. Типа такого,
"
Главное меню
1. Загрузка системы
2. Выключить платформу
3. Настройки платформы
"

На самой платформе есть 3 разные менюшки для настройки разных параметров, bios, прослойка между bios и операционной системой, операционная система. И *если в bios и ОС текст приходит нормальный, то в Прослойке вместо русского слова "Нет" приходят байты (байты показываю в десятичных значениях, чтобы было удобнее сопоставлять с таблицами кодировок) "72, 101, 42", что декодируется как "He**", причем здесь вместо ожидаемой кириллицы будут латинские буквы и знак  * . Проблема в том, что ошибка вряд ли в кодировке,  тк уже на уровне байтов понятно, что там лежат эти символы (He*). Платформа с raspberry соединены переходником serial-usb. Параметры последовательного подключения - 115200 baud, 8 бит данных. (с параметрами подключения ошибки быть не может)

Вопрос следующий, может ли  COM порт / переходник принимать  неверные байты, ставя вместо кириллицы звездочки?

Comment: Порту и переходнику наплевать на кодировку, они байты данных никак не интерпретируют

Comment: Может они просто неправильно приняли байты для кириллицы и потом драйвер порта заменил их на "*", такое может быть?

Comment: В какой кодировке источник данных посылает русское "Нет"? Какая последовательность байтов уходит в порт?

Comment: кодировка - oem866. Какая последовательность байтов отсылается источником неизвестно, скидываю то что принимается: b'\x48\x65\2A'

Comment: мда, из  `8D A5 E2` 866-ой кодировки непросто сделать `48 65 2A`. Из закономерностей - инверсия двух старших битов, но в младшем ниббле разные изменения

Answer (score 0):

Терминал  может быть настроен на трансляцию русских символов в похожие. Нужно попытаться определить тип терминала и отправить управляющую последовательность для перевода из аски режима в режим кодировки.

Comment: Ты имеешь ввиду терминал, через который я смотрю вывод COM-порта?

Comment: Я имею ввиду терминал, который в ком порту рисует кнопки. На той стороне